# I tried to type some numbers on Number finding in Python, but it doesn't get any numbers

Tags: python

So, this code is about to input numbers and get the maximum, minimum, and average numbers.  But I am still in trouble whether I coded properly or not.

The main code to get numbers and results:
findnums_import.py

```
from utils import find_max, find_min, find_avg
import random

numslist = [0]


def printresult(numslist):
    thebiggest = find_max(numslist, number)
    thesmallest = find_min(numslist, number)
    theavg = find_avg(numslist, number)
    print(f"Biggest Num: {thebiggest} \nSmallest Num: {thesmallest} \nAverage: {theavg}")


for number in numslist:
    while True:
        inputnum = input("Please insert numbers. If you finished please type 'f': ")
        if inputnum == float and int:
            number = inputnum
            numslist.append(number)
            print(f"The Number {number} has been added, \nSo There are \n{numslist}")
        elif inputnum.lower() == 'f':
            printresult(numslist)
            break
        else:
            print("Please type the proper data. ")
            pass
```

...and the code to get the maximum, minimum and average values:
utils.py

```
def find_max(numslist, number):
    thebiggest = numslist[0]
    for number in numslist:
        if number > thebiggest:
            thebiggest = number
    return thebiggest


def find_min(numslist, number):
    thesmallest = numslist[0]
    for number in numslist:
        if number < thesmallest:
            thesmallest = number
    return thesmallest


def find_avg(numslist, number):
    sum_ = 0
    theavg = 0
    # numscount = 0
    for number in numslist:
        sum_ += number
        theavg = sum_ / len(numslist)

        '''
        If numscount is used but not theavg: 
        sum_=sum_+number
        numscount+=1
        '''
    return theavg
```

When I type some numbers,

````
Please type the proper data. 
Please insert numbers. If you finished please type 'f': 1
Please type the proper data. ```
I really can't input the number and when I type f; 
```Please insert numbers. If you finished please type 'f': f
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/findnums_import_practice_r4378to_WIP/findnums_import.py", line 24, in <module>
    printresult(numslist)
  File "C:/Users/user/PycharmProjects/findnums_import_practice_r4378to_WIP/findnums_import.py", line 12, in printresult
    theavg = find_avg(numslist, number)
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\findnums_import_practice_r4378to_WIP\utils.py", line 23, in find_avg
    theavg = sum_ / numslist.len(numslist)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'len'
````

There is an AttributeError so I can't progress more.

Comment: You have not shown the full code that has the error, but looking at the stacktrace, it looks like instead of `numslist.len(numslist)` it should just say `len(numslist)` - at line 23 of `utils.py`

Comment: also a number cannot be float and int simultaneously. you need to add ```or``` instead of ```and``` and why is the 0 initially in the numslist?

Comment: This line if `inputnum == float and int:` will never be true. That is not how you test the type of input data. Look at the built-in function `isinstance()`.

Comment: @YashShah When I removed 0 in that array, the program doesn't work and just finish the process.

Comment: @user14120588 it is simply because you have added ```for number in numslist:
``` if there would be no number in the numslist, how would it iterate. i would suggest removing that line and start directly with ```while True```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the builtin function `len(obj)` (in find_avg) which invokes `obj.__len__()`.

```
$> Python
>>> numlist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> len(numlist)
5
>>> numlist.__len__()
5
```